# Excel macro - type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

im a noob.

My macro adds a date when a cell value changes to "Closed".
Specifically,  when a cell value in column M changes to "Closed", it adds the date 2 cells to the left, in column K.
Works perfectly, until i **edit more than one cell in either column**. If i do that, i get a 13 type mismatch error.

This sucks as it means an error comes up each time i autofill.

[Click for image of problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI2M4.png)

thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 13 And Target = "Closed" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -2) = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If cell.Column = 13 And cell = "Closed" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -2) = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: perfect! i didnt know how to do the     For Each **cell** In Target